# Fazer requisição GET através de um WebView

Tags: objective-c, get, iphone, webview

Estou com um problema ao tentar enviar uma requisição via get para uma WebView abrir o contendo de uma pagina, quando eu passo os paramentos concatenados ocorre um erro, creio que seja por motivos de codificação isso só ocorre quando passo parâmetros com caracteres especiais, alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa questão? Segue o codigo que estou utilizando.

```
NSString *titulo = [listDictionary objectForKey:@"titulo"];
NSString *imagem = [listDictionary objectForKey:@"imagem"];
NSString *descricao = [listDictionary objectForKey:@"descricao"];

NSString *getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://meudominio.com.br/web.php?titulo=%@&image=%@&conteudo=%@", titulo, imagem, descricao];


getString = [getString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Podes informar qual o erro está dando? Tenta utilizando o encoding UTF8 (NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho uma função para esses casos. É preciso converter o texto dos valores da chamada GET para o chamado Percent Encoding, mas os caracteres '&' e '?' não estão incluídos nessa conversão do Objective-C (lembrando também que é preciso escolher o encoding UTF-8 nessa função). Faça uma extensão (extension) do NSString e adicione o seguinte:

```
-(NSString*)stringToWebStructure
{
    NSString* webString = [self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];

    return webString;
}
```

E então substitua isso:

```
NSString *getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://meudominio.com.br/web.php?titulo=%@&image=%@&conteudo=%@", titulo, imagem, descricao];


getString = [getString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getString];
```

Por isso:

```
NSString *getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://meudominio.com.br/web.php?titulo=%@&image=%@&conteudo=%@", titulo.stringToWebStructure, imagem.stringToWebStructure, descricao.stringToWebStructure];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getString];
```

Esse é mais um detalhe importante: não se deve converter a URL inteira, apenas os valores dos argumentos, afinal o resto da URL já está em um formato aceitável.